# CentOS - Allow FTP access through IPtables

Tags: centos, ftp, port

Sorry guys for the stupid question, but I can't open my FTP (ProFTPd) from browser on CentOS 6.5. When I stop IPtables I don't have problem, but when is running I have.

Port 21 is open, port 20 is not (I don't know how to open it).

EDIT 1:

The output from "iptables -L -n"

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8000 
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

EDIT 2:
@HBruijn His way work for me.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `iptables -L -n` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't phrased very well, but the symptoms you describe are indicative of a passive FTP not working correctly in combination with your firewall.

Typically the command `insmod nf_conntrack_ftp` is sufficient to load the FTP helper module in a badly configured RHEL6 or CentOS firewall.

To make that persistent:

Edit the configuration file `/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config` and add the helper module `nf_conntrack_ftp` to the IPTABLES_MODULES variable:

```
IPTABLES_MODULES="nf_conntrack_ftp"
```

or add it to any other modules already listed there.

Answer (score 0):

You can either directly edit the iptables config file `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` then restart the iptables service.  Or modify then save the running config.    As root, or sudo:

```
# If using a custom chain for this sort of thing, APPEND port to chain:
iptables -A MYCHAIN -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```

If you have a REJECT line in your INPUT chain,  you'll want to make sure the port you're adding to the firewall is inserted before the REJECT:

```
# List the Chain with line numbers
iptables -L INPUT -n --line-numbers

# in this example 7 is REJECT line from the above,  this will push the REJECT line down
# and insert this right above it:
iptables -I INPUT 7 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
```

also dont forget to do the same for `ip6tables` if required.